# its possible run a virtual box with no GUI?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I have Virtualbox installed on Windows 10 with 3 virtual machines, but I would like to optimize the computer using ubuntu server for register two more virtual machines (these run windows xp)

its possible?

Thanks

Comment: this is a bit confusing. What's your *intended* host? the fact that you're running windows now is unimportant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run VirtualBox in background, without a window?](http://superuser.com/questions/135498/run-virtualbox-in-background-without-a-window)

Comment: [How can I start a VM without getting a window?](http://superuser.com/q/72449/241386)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an option to start the VMs in Headless mode.  Headless mode basically runs the VM like you would normally, but doesn't show the screen or GUI of the VM.  In version 5 of Virtualbox, there should be an arrow pointing down next to the button to start VMs.  If you click on it, you can start the VM in headless mode.  If you want to use the command line to start your VMs in headless mode you can use [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless).